# Native Array in Emberjs does not support deep copy?

Tags: ember.js

Native Array in Emberjs does not support deep copy? I saw it just returning sliced array in the copy method. Is it a bug?

Comment: seems fixed now https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, that's an improvement going on Ember, reported by @adamjmurray: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/588

There's also a proposition to implement it. You can use it like this:

```
var NativeArray = Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.NativeArray, {
    copy: function(deep) {
        if (deep) {
            return this.map(function(item){ return Ember.copy(item, true) });
        } else {
            return this.slice();
        }
    }
});

NativeArray.apply(Array.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

In `Ember.Copyable` the comments state that there should be a boolean parameter that if true would produce a deep copy, but obviously it's not implemented yet. You can always override it with your own method. Something like this would work for simple objects (**note**: untested so consider this pseudocode)

```
copy: function(deep) {
  if(deep) return $.extend(true, [], this);
  else return this._super();
}
```