# How to add a method to []?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

First of all, I don't understand clearly what the type of this object (perhaps NativeArray ?). For me ember overrides the default javascript array with some mixins, by applying the NativeArray mixin to Array.prototype.

That beeing said, in my code, I want to do this kind of override by allowing:

```
["a", "b", "a"].count("a") // returns 2
```

I was trying to reopen the Enumerable Mixin (as for me it's the right place for this kind of function)

I'm sure that the reopen code is executed before using the count() method. But I encounter this error:

```
Object has no method count().
```

Reading the code it seems that I have to re-apply the mixin to the Array.prototype, but unfortunately, doing `Ember.Enumerable.apply(Array.prototype)` does nothing.

**Update:**
After reading some articles, I begin to understand the prototype. I can add a function to an array with:

```
Array.prototype.newFunc = function () {
    console.log('bla');
}
```

But in my case, it's not satisfying as I want that for example, a MutableArray will be able to call `newFun()`

Perhaps the only way to do what I want is to make a PR to ember to include my count method to the Enumerable Mixin....

Any other suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: Did you already check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693154/native-array-in-emberjs-does-not-support-deep-copy not sure you want the excat thing.

Comment: You should not override built-in object prototypes. We are in the post-Prototype.js era!

Comment: `[] instanceof Array // true`

Comment: @Florent Well, that's debatable... ;) Augmenting Native Objects isn't that bad when done properly. Enhancing Host-Objects is worse.

Comment: @Florent I don't even know what exactly is the prototype area ^^. I began web app dev with ember, and I am discovering the internal of javascript...

Comment: @sabithpocker I think this does not work for me, as I want that all "subclasses" of enumerable (including the ones defined in ember) will benefit of my new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% on this, so read it with a bit of skepticism.  Looks like mixins have two main paths you can follow when updating and creating.  One is the "reopen" method, this ends up adding another mixin to the object.  The second is "apply" which actually merges these mixins down into the object itself and you lose the mixin reference.  So, updating Ember.Enumerable pretty much will gain you nothing unless you use it in a new class you define.

You could always fire that "apply" method on all Enumerable types but is kind of a pain... Maybe some detect hack that searched and returned all main classes... meh.

The other solution is to fork the repo and add the method (probably will save you a huge headache & time.... you did say something about this).  I think back in 9.8 you used to be able to do this kind of thing, but these later builds present a problem to exactly this.

**Edit**: To clarify, by "merge" I really mean copied the actual methods onto another object.  Such as to the (Array.prototype)...  So the 'detect' will find the Ember.Enumerable but that Mixin is not really reference by the Array anymore (methods were copied over earlier).

I guess you could just create a new mixin and apply it to types as you need it (you just have to remember you are doing that explicitly).  Right now, if you only need it on Array you just apply it to the Array.prototype.  Next time when you need it on, lets say ArrayController, you add it.

Made a [simple fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/JykhF/) but it is pretty much the same as the other guys post.  I still don't like this much as forking the repo.

Comment: The guy who has downvoted could at least explain why. I think this is not a wrong answer... nothing seems to be false here.

Comment: On another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811586/stop-changing-offset-on-hover-jquery/11811699#11811699); my answer replaced an already accepted response.  A couple hours later a bunch of my answers including accepted ones were down-voted & he deleted his original answer.  Kind of figured he took it a little personally, but again; just a presumption.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the fiddle. I'll accecpt this answer as it's the most complete, and explain deeply what's going on. Though, I think I will simply use `arrayLike.filter().get('length')`

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `reopen`, it allows you to modify an existing class. Here is an example:

```
Ember.Enumerable.reopen({
    newFunc: function() {
        console.log('blah');
    }
});
```

**WARNING**: Calling `reopen` will not have an effect on objects which have already been instantiated. It will only effect objects created AFTER reopen has been called. In short, make sure you do `reopen` calls first.

Comment: Yep, I tried to use reopen. (mentioned in my question). But in fact, this does'nt work in my case. It happens exactly what you describe in your warning clause. I wonder if I can apply this new Enumerable mixin on all classes implementing it.

Comment: I don't understand why users upvote has it does not anwer to my question. Anyway it does'nt matter

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/249/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

var NativeArray = Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.NativeArray, {
    count: function(ele) {
        var noOfEle = 20;
        //add your logic to count
        return noOfEle;
    }
});

NativeArray.apply(Array.prototype);
console.log(["a", "b", "a"].count("a")); //20
```

REF: [Native Array in Emberjs does not support deep copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693154/native-array-in-emberjs-does-not-support-deep-copy)

Comment: I was commentting your suggestion. I think it will not work in my case, as I want to be able to call the count() method from all Enumerable subclasses. Perhaps I have to modify my question. I will do it if I get no other answers...